# Regex Expressions For Emoji

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, emoji

http://jsfiddle.net/bxeLyneu/1/

```
function custom() {
var str = document.getElementById('original').innerHTML;
var replacement = str.replace(/\B:poop:\B/g,'REPLACED');
document.getElementById('replaced').innerHTML = replacement;
}
custom()
```

Yes = :poop: should be replaced with "REPLACED"
No = :poop: should not be replaced. In other words, remain untouched.

Number 4, 5, 6 doesn't seems to follow the rule provided. I do know why, but I don't have much idea how to combine multiple expressions into one. 
I have tried many others but I just can't get them to work the way I wanted them to be. Odds aren't in my favor.

And yes, this is very similar to how Facebook emoji in chat box works.

**New issue:**

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/xaekh8op/13/

```
/(^|\s):bin:(\s|$)/gm
```

It is unable to scan and replace the one in the middle.
How can I fix that?

Comment: `/\s:poop:\s/g` fits the expected examples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\B` means "Any location not at a word boundary" whereas `\s` means "Whitespace". Based upon your given examples, the following code works perfectly.

```
function custom() {
    var str = document.getElementById('original').innerHTML;
    var replacement = str.replace(/([\s>]|^):poop:(?=[\s<]|$)/gm,'$1REPLACED');
    document.getElementById('replaced').innerHTML = replacement;
}
custom()
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xaekh8op/15/

**Explanation:**

The regular expression `([\s>]|^):poop:(?=[\s<]|$)` stands for the following:

[image: Regular expression visualization] (image created in Debuggex)

By picking one of `\s` and `>` at the start (or using `^` meaning start of line), and grouping it as group 1, we can use it later. Similarly for after the `:poop:` (`\s` or `<` or end-of-line `$`). However, the second time, it is done using a look-ahead (`(?= ...)` is the syntax), which checks whether the `[\s<]|$` portion is there after, but it doesn't consume it in the replacement. The `<` and `>` take care of any HTML tags that might be just beside the `:poop:`. The `$1` in the replacement string `$1REPLACED` places the first group back, thereby rendering only the `:poop:` being replaced with `REPLACED`. The second "group" was just a look-ahead, and thus does not need to be replaced back.

For further information on word boundaries, you can refer to  http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html which says:

> There are three different positions that qualify as word boundaries:
>
> - Before the first character in the string, if the first character is a word character.
> - After the last character in the string, if the last character is a word character.
> - Between two characters in the string, where one is a word character and the other is not a word character.

Comment: What if the spaces were not present in both front and back? It's not going to work.

Comment: @Jahid, fixed answer for that using capture groups.
@NubPro, fixed answer for that using test with `>` and `<` as well.
Please check new demo with extra test cases added which demonstrate the code.

Comment: Ah! Didn't anticipate that. Fixed. Check latest edit.

Comment: Interestingly, jsfiddle.net/xaekh8op/10 but I'm uncertain why my codes work.

Comment: oh damn....so how can I make sure `:poop: :poop:`, both of them getting replaced?

Comment: been trying for a few hours now, but I couldn't think of feasible solution. Please assist.

Comment: @NubPro: Fixed for that as well. Please check latest edit.  
Damn, this question is fun. So many corner cases to take care off :D  
Hopefully, the latest edit takes care of all cases properly :)